# use IO::Socket::IP ??? how to make a client in perl Ipv6

Tags: perl, client, ipv6

I have been trying to find a simple client ipv6 script 
that would work with Evens server script , of course I 
dont know what Im doing, so all I can do is rewrite someone 
else's work until I know what Im doing ...

so here is a server script that works on Microsoft widows server

```
   use IO::Socket::IP -register; 
   my $sock = IO::Socket->new(
   Domain    => PF_INET6,
   LocalHost => "::1",
   Listen    => 1,
   ) or die "Cannot create socket - $@\n";

   print "Created a socket of type " . ref($sock) . "\n";

   {
   $in = <STDIN>;
   print $in->$sock;
   redo }
```

of course the $in->$sock is not working, cause I dont know how to send 
data using just $sock ???
so I need to know how to send information properly and
what I need is A client script to connect to the above script
using the ipv6 protocol

can anyone help with this ???
I would like to be able to send information from one 
perl program to another perl program using this 
being able to send information back and forth would 
be Ideal ...

Thanks in advance 
-Mark

Answer (score 1):

That's a server socket (`Listen => 1`), so you have to `accept` a connection.

```
use IO::Socket::IP -register;

my $listen_sock = IO::Socket::IP->new(
   LocalHost => "::1",                    # bind()
   Listen    => 1,                        # listen()
) or die "Cannot create socket - $@\n";

print("Listening to ".$listen_sock->sockhost()." "
                     .$listen_sock->sockport()."\n");

while (1) {
   my $sock = $listen_sock->accept()
      or die $!;

   print("Connection received from ".$sock->peerhost()." "
                                    .$sock->peerport()."\n");

   while (<$sock>) {
      print $sock "echo: $_";
   }
}
```

A client:

```
use IO::Socket::IP -register;

@ARGV == 2 or die("usage");
my ($host, $port) = @ARGV;

my $sock = IO::Socket::IP->new(
   PeerHost => $host,                     # \ bind()
   PeerPort => $port,                     # /
) or die "Cannot create socket - $@\n";

print $sock "Hello, world!\n";
$sock->shutdown(1);                       # Done writing.
print while <$sock>;
```

The comments indicate the underlying system call used to perform the action.

Comment: Pass the address and port as arguments.

Comment: is there a way to use the same port over again with out useing $sock->shutdown(1); if you sending a lot of information then you go through a lot of ports, and it ends up blocking all other ports and shutting down all communications, cause you have a bunch of ports that are waiting .. is there a way to flush the same port and use it over again ...

Comment: sure. I just made the server continue until EOF, but you don't have to do that.

Comment: The blocking has nothing to do with shutdown. You'll have to use some for of multitasking (e.g. threads) or `select` or non-blocking reads if you want to handle multiple connections in parallel. That's waaaaaaaay beyond your question.