# How to find the IPv6 address of a client using Perl CGI script

Tags: perl, networking, ipv6, ipv4

In perl getting the external IPv4 address of a client is done by doing this:

```
$ip4_address = $ENV{"REMOTE_ADDR"};
```

What would you do to get the external IPv6 address from the client.

(Note that I need the external IPv6 address of the client connecting to the web server - **I'm not trying to get the IPv6 address of a domain name**)

Comment: [Perl supports IPv6](https://www.perl.org/about/whitepapers/perl-ipv6.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Domain name to IPv6 address in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574821/domain-name-to-ipv6-address-in-perl)

Comment: [How to make a client in perl Ipv6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16908163/4248931)

Comment: I'm referring to a client and not a domain name. (The client connecting to the web server or domain name)

Answer (score 4):

The `REMOTE_ADDR` CGI variable is simply populated from the peer address of the incoming HTTP connection. If that's over IPv6, then it'll be an IPv6 address. If it's over IPv4, then a IPv4 one.

If the client connects to you over IPv4, you can't know anything about the state of their IPv6 stack unless they tell you, and there isn't a common way that's done.

In summary: you can't know.